# Is a 'ConcurrentQueue' the best way to handle a desired process that's similar to 'bank account transaction' code in C#?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

The general overview is that I'm trying to formulate code similar to how a bank would handle it's account transactions.  For example, two requests to debit money from the same account could never be executed at the same time because that could result in an overdrawn account.

A quick summary of the key tasks include the following:

1. This code is being written into a RESTful api following OData standards so a response needs to be provided to every request with a link to the newly created resource.
2. Two requests for the same resource can never be processed at the same time.

Based on the research I've done so far it seems like a ConcurrentQueue would be the way to go due to it's thread safety, however, I don't see how an IHttpActionResult response could be provided to each request containing a link to the new resource since it appears that the only request that would get a response is the last one in the queue.

Below is the code that I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<MarketUnitAdjustmentModel> _createMarketUnitAdjustmentQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<MarketUnitAdjustmentModel>();

public ServiceResponseModel CreateMarketUnitAdjustment(MarketUnitAdjustmentModel marketUnitAdjustment)
    {
        var serviceResponseModel = new ServiceResponseModel();

        _createMarketUnitAdjustmentQueue.Enqueue(marketUnitAdjustment);
        MarketUnitAdjustmentModel nextEntryInQueue;
        while (_createMarketUnitAdjustmentQueue.TryDequeue(out nextEntryInQueue))
        {
            serviceResponseModel = AddMarketUnitAdjustment(nextEntryInQueue);
        };

        return serviceResponseModel;
    }
```

The Controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [EnableQuery]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created)]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)]
    public IHttpActionResult Post (MarketUnitAdjustmentModel key)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var serviceResponseModel = _marketUnitAdjustmentService.CreateMarketUnitAdjustment(key);
            if (!serviceResponseModel.IsSuccessful)
            {
                //This response needs to be updated to a BadRequest or something similar
                return Ok(serviceResponseModel.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                // HTTP Status code of Created returns location of newly created person and the ID of that person.
                var location = Request.RequestUri + "(" + serviceResponseModel.EntityId + ")";
                return Created(location, serviceResponseModel.EntityId);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
```

The ServiceResponseModel looks like this:

```
public class ServiceResponseModel
{
    public bool IsSuccessful { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int? EntityId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thread safe collections like ConcurrentQueue is useful when you actually work with multiple threads. In your case, those two debit money transactions are going to be two different requests rather than spawning two tasks/threads in a single request. So of its two different requests, aint a new ConcurrentQueue be instanciated for every request? May be you are looking for database transactions which would temporarily locks the resource when in use so that a parallel query is not executed against it.

Comment: Update-- just noticed that you have a static list, so new list will not be created for every request as I mentioned above. But still how different would be the execution even if you don't use any queues there? You are just dequeuing and executing the `AddMarketUnitAdjustment` method which is more or less the same which would have happened without using queues. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> For example, two requests to debit money from the same account could never be executed at the same time because that could result in an overdrawn account.

Bank accounts get overdrawn overtime, so there is a flaw in your premise.

> The general overview is that I'm trying to formulate code similar to how a bank would handle it's account transactions

A banking transaction follows what might be characterized as a sort of [two phase commit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol).  When you request money to move, a [memo post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memo_posting) is created.  The actual money movement doesn't happen until end of day reconciliation and requires a sort of distributed [double-entry mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-entry_bookkeeping_system).

In practice, the actual money movement is full of quirks and abnormalities because it cannot be fully automated due to the differences in all the (very old) systems.  Therefore there must also be [clawback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clawback) capabilities.  In addition, money often held in a [clearing account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clearing_account) to ensure that it is committed to neither party until all the quirks have been resolved.  This also has the benefit of granting the bank interest while the money sits in their account.

It is also worth noting that banking transactions are not queued, processed, and discarded.  Once they are created, they exist forever (in part for [auditability](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/auditability.asp) purposes).  To "delete" a transaction you actually create a second, offsetting transaction.

Are you actually trying to model a banking system or were you just using that as an analogy?  Because implementing a queue is probably not the right approach.  Instead you should be working with a workflow data structure, double entry accounting, and interstitial repository structures.

I'm guessing your question has an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

While John Wu's answer looks at real-world banking applications, I understand your question more as an analogy.

The main issue for bank transfer is the "exclusive access to resources". When you start the transaction, get exclusive access to the account from which to transfer, check if it fulfills the conditions that the transaction can be done, get exclusive access to the other account, check if it fulfills the conditions, perform the transaction, release the resources.

Mechanisms for the exclusive access are e.g. Monitor/lock, Semaphores, etc. Make sure you do not run into dead locks!

Comment: @John Wu and Bernhard - I appreciate both of your replies.  I'm new to the concepts of multi-threading and since posting my question I've learned that our code doesn't use a singleton structure so I guess my solution to our problem wouldn't actually fix the issue.  It sounds like a stored procedure might be the best way for us to prevent illegal transactions (aka transactions that don't meet the logic requirements) but we've decided that the concern is negligible due to it's minimal usage.